# How do I only display the newest document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I have mongoose searching for one document on Node.JS/Discord.JS and I have it sort for `{ date: -1 }` and it still sends the oldest document in the database.
Here is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
gLog.
  findOne({ "GiveawayHostID": name }).
  sort({ date: -1}).
  exec(function (err, host) {
```

Here is the schema used above:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const gLogSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  GiveawayHost: String,
  GiveawayHostID: String,
  Prize: String,
  WinnerUsername: String,
  WinnerUsernameID: String,
  time: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("GiveawayLogs", gLogSchema)
```

Comment: Can you show your Schema?

Comment: Edited it to show the schema.

Comment: How will you sort `date`, if you don't have a `date` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you do not have a `date` field in your schema, so mongoose is not able to sort by date. You can sort by time with:

```
findOne({ "GiveawayHostID": name }).
sort({ time: -1}).
exec(function (err, host) {
```

However, this probably won't return the expected results, as your `time` field is marked as a `String`. So mongoose will sort your times in alphabetical order.

To fix this, you can change your `time` variable to a `timestamp` format. Otherwise, you will need to add the `date` field to your schema and follow [this example](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#dates).

Answer (score 0):

You could just sort it by **_id** field this is a BSON data type that starts with timestamp due to which you could sort it by insertion timestamp which will always give you latest record if you don't create you custom _id and let mongodb create one see more info [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid)

so all you have to do is:

```
findOne({ "GiveawayHostID": name }).
sort({ _id: -1}).
exec(function (err, host) {
```

Just to quote important bit from documentation:

> ObjectIds are small, likely unique, fast to generate, and ordered.
>   ObjectId values consist of 12 bytes, where the first four bytes are a
>   timestamp that reflect the ObjectId’s creation. Specifically:
>
> - **4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,**
> - 5-byte random value, and
> - 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.